# In MySQL using CAST() to CAST VARCHAR to CHAR, but end result is still VARCHAR and not CHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I create a table `table1` with a single column `column1` declared as `VARCHAR(100)` -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    -> column1 VARCHAR(100)
    -> );
```

```
DESCRIBE table1;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column1 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I create another table `table2` from `table1` where I create a single column `column2` and declaring it by casting `column1` from `table1` as `CHAR(100)` -

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
    -> SELECT CAST(column1 AS CHAR(100)) AS column2
    -> FROM table1;
```

```
DESCRIBE table2;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column2 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here, strangely enough, even after casting `VARCHAR(100)` AS `CHAR(100)`, the declaration still remains as `VARCHAR(100)`

Now, I wanted to make sure that creating a new table with column declared by casting actually works. So I tried with casting `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL` as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    -> column3 FLOAT
    -> );
```

```
DESCRIBE table3;
+---------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column3 | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE table4 AS 
    -> SELECT CAST(column3 AS DECIMAL) AS column4
    -> FROM table3;
```

```
DESCRIBE table4;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column4 | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here `FLOAT` gets correctly casted to `DECIMAL`. So why can't I cast `VARCHAR` to `CHAR`. Also if casting of `VARCHAR` to `CHAR` doesn't work, why am I not getting any error?

Comment: You probably need to declare the table with the exactly types you want and then load the data -- or alter the table afterwards.  MySQL doesn't give full control of types via `cast()`.

Comment: `SELECT CAST(column1 AS CHAR(100))` adding CAST in the SELECT statement will not change the structure of TABLE, it will affect only that SELECT statement. DESCRIBE table will show the structure of the table. VARCHAR is also CHAR with variable length.

Comment: @aRvi but in second example of mine, I am successfully changing `FLOAT` to `DECIMAL` using the same `CAST` operation

Comment: @PayelSenapati . . . floats and decimals are different enough that they have different representations, so the data representation needs to be converted.

Comment: @aRvi that is plain wrong. Of course there is `CHAR` type in MySQL

Comment: @aRvi https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here, strangely enough, even after casting VARCHAR(100) AS CHAR(100), the declaration still remains as VARCHAR(100)

This is not strange behavior.  It is clearly [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

> - CHAR[(N)] [charset_info]
>
> Produces a string with the VARCHAR data type. except that when the expression expr is empty (zero length), the result type is CHAR(0).

I'm the first to admit that it is rather counterintuitive, but it is how MySQL works.  If you want a `char()` then either create the table with that type and insert into it or alter it afterwards.

Comment: Can you please give me a link where I can study binary data type? I am having difficulty in understanding binary data type. Thank you.

Comment: @PayelSenapati . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html.

Comment: can you please give any non-documentation link, like any easy to understand tutorial please? thank you